# Exposing Joomla component view at root URL endpoint

Tags: php, html, joomla, components

I'm new to joomla, and I am trying to write an installable Joomla component which exposes a HTML page at this URL: `http://localhost/joomla/someurl` (Joomla is installed at /joomla/)

Here is what I've already done:

1. I created a basic component in the `/joomla/components/` folder in my install
2. I added a controller, a `router.php` and created a view to be displayed. My component's name is `mycomponent`
3. I tried accessing my `default` view page through several means. The following work:

   - `/joomla/components/mycomponent`
   - `/joomla/index.php?option=com_mycomponent`

I have the following questions:

1. How do I expose my component's view at a given URL endpoint? I want the contents of the default view to appear at `/joomla/arbitraryurl/`
2. What is the best way of presenting a standalone HTML page without using the Joomla layout (i.e. a naked html page)
3. What is the best way to link to CSS and JS resources which are present in my component folder from my HTML making sure the right URL is reached.

Comment: You mean to say you want to create a sef friendly url's ?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Can't you use a menu link, if your view is linked to a menu item Joomla will generate the url automatically.
All is explained here if you want to allow users to link your view in a menu http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part

If you can't link this view to a menu item, I use a system plugin for some specific cases.
The system plugin will augment JRouter and you will be able to route to your component for any url.

```
//-- No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') || die('=;)');


class plgSystemYourplugin extends JPlugin
{

    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
       $app = JFactory::getApplication();
      // get the router
      if ($app->isSite()) {
    $router = $app->getRouter();                
    $router->attachParseRule(array($this, 'replaceRoute'));
      }
    }

    /**
     * @param   JRouterSite &$router  The Joomla Site Router
     * @param   JURI  &$uri  The URI to parse
     *
     * @return  array  $vars The array of processed URI variables
     */
    public function replaceRoute (&$router, &$uri)
    {
    $array = array();

    $yourURI = 'whateverIwant' //here is your custom uri
    $UriSegs = sizeof(explode('/',$yourURI));
    $Segs = explode('/',$yourURI);

    $path = explode('/',$uri->getPath());

    if(count($Segs) < count($path)){
        for ($index = $UriSegs-1; $index < count($Segs); $index++) {
            if($Segs[$index]!==$path[$index]){
                return $array;
            }
        }
        if(!isset($path[1]) || $path[1]===''){
            return $array;
        }

        JRequest::setVar('option','com_yourcomponent');
        JRequest::setVar('view','yourView');

        $uri->reset();
    }

    return $array;            
     }

}
```

This will redirect the user to  index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourView if he was requiring the page http://yourdomaine.com/whateverIwant

More infos here: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_System_Plugin_to_augment_JRouter

2/ You can just add to the url &tmp=component, Joomla will remove the standard template and modules and it will just render the component.

3/ You can use

For scripts:

`$document->addScript(JURI::root().'components/com_yourcomponent/assets/js/script.js');`

For css files:

`$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root().'components/com_yourcomponent/assets/css/style.css');`

More infos here http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript and http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet